# Optimization with unbalanced data from multiple experiments

Tags: time-series, optimization, unbalanced-classes

My observations are leaf number of wheat which obtained from multiple experiments. The number of observations are depending on experiment which ranged from 1 to 10. In each experiment, leaf number is a time serial values from 1 to 7.

A processed based crop model [APSIM](https://github.com/APSIMInitiative/ApsimX/) is used to predict leaf number. A optimization procedure is used then to optimize two parameters in the model.

Currently, the optimization procedure is based on the minimum [mean squared variation (MSV)](https://acsess.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.2134/agronj2000.922345x) to select the better parameters.

All the observations are directly used to calculate MSV during optimization.

My question are

- how to treat all experiments with the same weight as curent method biases to experiment with more observations (experiments with smaller number observations have more errors)?
- how to deal with the time serial data as the current method biases to bigger values (See Exp7 below)?

See picture below for current comparison of observed and predicted leaf number.

[image]

Comment: I assume the two parameters of the model are the ones that define the black line in the plots. am I right?

Comment: No the parameters are inside the crop model. The crop model is to simulate the interaction of environmal, genotype and managments with complicated equations. The black line is the 1 vs 1 to compare the observations and predictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt at an answer.  This might take a little iteration to make it match your situation directly.

1. how to treat all experiments with the same weight as curent method biases to experiment with more observations (experiments with smaller number observations have more errors)?

As you will see in my simulation, I'm not sure this is really a problem yet.  But if, in your data, it is a problem, then here may be a way to mitigate this:  fit the parameters on each experiment, then average the experiment-wise fits.  I don't recommend this yet though.

2. how to deal with the time serial data as the current method biases to bigger values (See Exp7 below)?

This might be an artifact of "capping" the observed data as you will see in simulation.  In other words, if no plants have more than 7 leaves, the model may need to treat this differently, or change the model form (e.g. 4 parameter logistic)

Simulation in R:

````r
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)
require(ggplot2)

# simulate data

# number of experiments
Ne <- 18

# min leaf number
minln <- 1

# max leaf number
maxln <- 7

# min observations per experiment
minobs <- 1

# max observations per experiment
maxobs <- 10

# max obsrvation time
tmax <- 20

# simple model, leaf number is a funciton of time
lnfun <- function(tim)
{
  pmin(maxln, pmax(minln, minln + (maxln - minln) * tim / tmax + rnorm(length(tim), 0, 0.5)))
}

set.seed(189439)
dat <- vector("list", length = Ne)
for (i in 1:Ne)
{
  nobs <- sample(minobs:maxobs, size = 1)
  tim <- seq(0, tmax, length = nobs)
  y <- lnfun(tim)
  dat[[i]] <- data.frame(tim = tim, y = y, exp = paste0("Exp", i))
}

dat <- do.call(rbind, dat)

# fit a model with two parameters across all the experiments
#   lm fits to minimize the mean squared error which is the same thing as the link for "mean square variation" in the question
lm1 <- lm(y ~ tim, data = dat)

dat$pred <- predict(lm1)

# this figure is close to the one posted
ggplot(dat, aes(x = y, y = pred, group = exp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(x = "observed leaf number", y = "predicted leaf number") +
  facet_wrap(~exp) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1)


# do experiments with smaller observations have larger errors?
#   There is insufficient evidence to conclude that in this simulation - what does the original data show?

datexp <- dat %>%
  dplyr::group_by(exp) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(merr = mean(y - pred),
            mabserr = mean(abs(y - pred)),
            msqerr = mean((y - pred)^2),
            n = length(y))
datexp

ggplot(datexp, aes(x = n, y = msqerr)) + geom_point()
summary(lm(msqerr ~ n, datexp))

# does the fit bias to larger values?  In other words, do larger observed values have smaller error?
#   This shouldn't happen, but in my simulation, it does, because I capped the upper and lower ends at 7 and 1

datlarge <- dat %>%
  dplyr::mutate(err = y - pred,
                sqerr = (y - pred)^2)
datlarge

ggplot(datlarge, aes(x = y, y = sqerr)) + geom_point()
summary(lm(sqerr ~ y, datlarge))

```
````